# Query by Id and making endpoint with slug flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I tried for making dynamic endpoints like this. Soon I realized it's good to be use ids instead for slugs for queries. How to do that?

```
@app.route('/post/<string:slug>')
def post(slug):
    post = Blogpost.query.filter_by(slug=slug).one()
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

**Using flask-sqlalchemy and PostgreSQL database**

Answer (score 0):

Literally just replace slug by id everywhere. Also, it's not bad to use slugs if they are UNIQUE. I use an underscore before id because it's a Python native function

```py
@app.route('/post/<_id>')
def post(_id):
    post = Blogpost.query.filter_by(id=int(_id)).one()
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

which you can also change to `post = Blogpost.query.get(id=int(_id))`. This is equivalent.

Comment: I know it works. But I want something that uses slug for endpoints and id for querying my database

Comment: But to get  the ID of the post to query the database, you need to query the database to get it, right? I don't understand your question then.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use `id` and `slug` in the URL, I believe SO itself uses this pattern.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63149461/query-by-id-and-making-endpoint-with-slug-flask-sqlalchemy
```

where `63149461` is the `id` of the post.

So in your case, you could use something like:

```py
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>/<string:slug>')
def post(post_id, slug):
    post = Blogpost.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```